# iPhone 4 sometimes crashing after hitting run OR stop on xcode 4

Tags: iphone, crash, xcode4

The app isn't crashing, the phone is crashing!

When I hit "run" on xcode sometimes the phone crashes. It freezes for 1 minute then restart itself with the apple logo. When it doesn't crash, after I hit "stop" on xcode, the phone crashes sometimes in the same manner.

It has never crash the simulator.

When I run the app directly from the iPhone, crashing NEVER happens. I suspect it's the link between iPhone and xcode that causes the crash?

Edit:
Other symptoms included ALL apps excluding default apps being deleted after the phone restarted itself.

Note: the phone was jailbroken 4.3.1. Maybe it was a bad jailbreak if that's possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a corrupt os on the phone, bad cable or corrupt drivers. The phone is expecting to be able to run the commands on the wire but the data at the end is corrupt resulting in the phone trying to execute something that causes an error.

I would recommend replacing the Restoring the phone and if that does not solve the problem then a new usb cable and fresh install of ITunes.

If that does not solve the problem then it may be a hardware malfunction on the phone itself. If its under warranty take it to the Apple Store and see if they can warranty it out for you.

EDIT:

Actually if you are under warranty I would take it to the apple store and show them the issue that you are having. They may do exactly what I just said and the USB Cable may not even cost you anything.

Comment: I restored the phone, phone stopped crashing.